# Defining a function in ASM and using it in Android NDK C++ code

Tags: android, c++, assembly, android-ndk, arm

I just need to create a function in ARM asm, which then has to be executed by C++ code, and all of that compiled using Android NDK.

Firstly, here are the contents of the file `MyNDK.h`:

```
package com.example.test.ndktest;

public class MyNDK {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("MyLibrary");
    }

    public native Integer addOne(int input);

}
```

In the file `com_example_test_ndktest_MyNDK.h` I have:

```
/* Includes and ifdefs */

extern jint* asmFunction(jint*);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_test_ndktest_MyNDK_addOne
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject, jint& input) {
    return *asmFunction(&input);
}

/* endifs */
```

Nothing special, just a definition of the translated native `addOne` function, which adds one to `input` parameter.

The usage of the `addOne` function is as follows:

In `MainActivity.java`:

```
...

jint number = 1234;

MyNDK ndk = new MyNDK;
myndk.addOne(number); // Now number must contain 1235

...
```

---

Now, here is the problem, I don't know how to link the `input` parameter (in `com_example_test_ndktest_MyNDK.h`)  to the asm code. In other words, I need the asm `.s` file.

I think that what may be useful is to read from the stack memory, which is where the `input` parameter has been saved, but I don't know how to do that in ARM asm, as I'm thinking I'm fully mixing asm syntaxes for different architectures.

As an example, I just want a simple asm function declaration called `asmFunction` that takes a `jint*` argument, adds one to that argument, and returns the address of the argument passed to it:

```
.global asmFunction
.type asmFunction, @function
asmFunction:
    ???
    ret         ; When I build the project, it says `Unrecognized opcode 'ret'´, maybe in ARM asm there is no `ret` opcode?
```

I think I need aclarations.

EDIT:

Apparently inline assembly is not an option because it doesn't even recognize mov instruction as seen in this simple program that puts the value `newnum` into address `number`:

```
int* number = new int(10);
int newnum = 42;

asm (
"mov %0,%1\n\t"     <---- Unsupported instruction mov
:"=r"(number)
:"r"(newnum)
);

return *number;
```

Comment: you could create your function in C and disassemble the object file to see which are the instructions.

Comment: But doesnt that disassemble the program taking into account the current machine I'm running in? I want to assemble for ARM, not x86_64 (my current machine)

Comment: _"maybe in ARM asm there is no `ret` opcode?"_ - if you want to write code in assembly language, the very _first_ thing to do would be to learn the basics of that assembly language, like, say, the instruction set...

Comment: http://gnutoolchains.com/arm-eabi/, use <prefix>-objdump. But it would be good to learn some arm assembly. Assembly languages can be VERY different from each other.

Comment: Write your function in C or C++, debug it and test it; call this your reference implementation so you know you have a working tested implementation.  Get the assembly output (of the reference function) and compare to the assembly you want to use.

Comment: You can also use `gcc -S` to see the assembly output of C compilation (I mean the NDK gcc, and you should provide correct machine target). It looks to me (according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html)) like defining empty `LOCAL_FILTER_ASM :=` (or some neutral shell command doing nothing) in `Android.mk` may actually leave the temporary `.S` files in $OBJ_DIRS for your inspection.

Comment: About inline assembly... my first google search yield some quite detailed description about gcc and ARM inline assembly [ARM GCC Inline Assembler Cookbook](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html).

You should try some examples from those, as I don't see any particular reason why inline assembly shouldn't work with NDK (also `clang` is trying hard to be compatible with `gcc`, only being a tiny bit more strict in some cases). But I can't figure out by quick look what's wrong with your example, weird.

Comment: Hello, there are no "call" or "ret" in ARM. Only blx like things exist.